# MercurialEclipse branches

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

How to pull changes from one branch to other in MercurialEclipse plugin?
I can't find any info. Also I saw few options: rebase and merge, but I'm afraid to use them, because I work on commercial project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a MercurialEclipse question - an answer for plain mercurial would be valid too. The short answer is to use merge. Merge will apply all changes that were made on the other branch to the current branch since the last merge (or since the branch point if there had never been a merge before).

Rebase removes the source changesets so usually isn't appropriate for applying changes from one named branch to another.

A 3rd option is to use transplant. This lets you chose specific changesets to apply onto the current branch.